# Select edges by length?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools, edges

Is it possible to select all edges with a specific length?

I have a very exotic problem. In a computer game model, there is audience projected on several billboards, and depending on a billboards width, I know the number of characters seen in that billboard.

I want to find out the approximate complete count of characters in the audience.

The problem is, that there are 4146 billboards, which I can't count by hand, but classify by their length at least, and then calculate it up:

[image]

Any way to select, for example, all the widest audience billboard edges seen on the terrace?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**.

Select an edge and press <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>*> Length*. By default this will select all other edges with equal length to the active edge.
By adjusting the options in the *redo panel* (<kbd>F6</kbd>) or at the bottom of tool shelf (<kbd>T</kbd>), you can also select edges with greater or lesser lengths and compare lengths with a threshold to select edges that are not *exactly* the same length, but similar.

[image]

Once you have a partial selection on the billboards you want to select, you can select all geometry connected to the selection with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. Or in the case of a plane, by switching to face select mode (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) while holding <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd>.

In **Blender 2.8** (and higher) the UI changed a bit:

[image: Blender 2.8 UI]

The *redo panel* is now called *Adjust Last Operation* (<kbd>F9</kbd>)

Make sure your are in *Edit Mode* and have choosen the right selection mode. It's *Edge select* (<kbd>2</kbd>) for the *Select > Select Similar > Length* option

Answer (score 5):

Being in *Edit Mode* select a desired mesh (or meshes) using a *face selection*. Then go to ***Select-->Select Similiar-->Perimeter*** *(or Area)*.
[image]

Comment: Also note that this is accessible from the keyboard with `Shift G` while in face select mode.

Comment: Perfect! Wish I could accept both answers =)

Comment: @Ray Koopa, right choice :). I think gandalf3 's answer is closer related to your question. Nice to hear I helped anyway :).